# Difference between Product Key and Serial Number

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, product-key

I just wanted to extract my activation keys of Windows 7 and 8 x64. I used several programs to test, if they produce the right results. In System screen > Details about windows activation I can see the last five digits of my currently used installation key. I used the programs Speccy and License Crawler.

License Crawler yields the right code which is called Product Key. Speccy on the other hand yields a Serial Number, which also has the format XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX, but is not the actual installation key.

So what is the second code (Serial Number) about?

Comment: What's the difference between a username and a password?  Think of the serial number as the username and the product key as the password.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! I got the difference but does the serial number in this case belong to the specific release build of the windows image?

Comment: Lots of technical details: http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/37590-Windows-8-Product-Key-Decoding Long story short: Win7 product keys contain no N, Win8 ones do, they use different algorithms to convert to binary. Some programs use the wrong algorithm when decoding binary product ID to product key, therefore showing a wrong key.

Comment: @McMannus More than likely, yes, but I don't know enough to give you a definite answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can think of the Serial Number as a VIN (Vehicle Identification Number) if that helps.  You can think of it as a person's name.  You can think of it as the bar code on a can of tuna.  The Serial Number is an identifier for that product or object.  If there was an issue with your particular object, product, or OS installation media, tracing the serial number could result in revealing a problem during production... as that serial number can be used to identify when and where something was manufactured.  That's down to the date, time, and location in a particular production facility.

The Product Key... that's not a serial number.  In this specific case (since cans of Tuna don't have Product Keys... unless you count the Can Opener) the Product Key is just that... a key.  The installation (identified by the serial number) is locked, and must be unlocked to be used.  To unlock (activate) it, you need the key.

A Serial Number can be publicly displayed.  It can be openly available and searched.  A Product Key must be kept out of the public eye and reach... which means you might say that a Serial Number is the number posted on your house or mailbox, while the Product Key is the key to your front door.

Comment: I would revise your analogy. A Serial Number is a unique identifier (ideally). So equating it to a VIN is quite accurate. However for cans of tuna, all the same products from the same vendor will have the same bar code and will not be unique from can to can.

Comment: Product Keys are tied to a license, such as OEM, retail, MSDN, etc...

Comment: @EBGreen While I agree that the bar code on tuna isn't unique to that can of tuna alone, the analogy is not Serial Number = Bar Code.  The Analogy is Serial Number = Public Identifier on Product.  Which, on a can of tuna, is the bar code.

Comment: @Keltari years ago, I had a job with Dollar Rent-a-Car, and we got a New Yorker in, and the key for it also started one of the Chrysler mini-vans.  And Product Keys are tied to a licence AND a product.  I never said they were tied to a single Serial Number

Comment: @BonGart In that case VIN would not be the proper analogy since while it does contain the product information (year, make, and model of the car), each VIN is a unique identifier for that specific car.

Comment: @EBGreen The problem with an analogy in general, is that it actually requires a modicum of imagination, and the ability to step away from the literal, to be able to understand.  For example, Autistic children have extreme difficulty with analogies.  If in an analogy one side were EXACTLY like the other, then the two would be the same, and an analogy would not be necessary.  Analogous = Comparable in certain respects, typically in a way that makes clearer the nature of the things compared.  Similar.  Not the same.

Answer (score 2):

I used to think this was straight forward until last week when I had to call Microsoft for help to move a Visio license. The person I spoke with asked me for the Product Key and I gave it to her from my account licensing page. But, she kept saying the was the Serial Number and not the Product Key. I kept saying, "It says Product Key right next to the number!"

When I asked the next tech support guy explained that internally, Microsoft refers to Product Keys as Serial Numbers. Now, that really helps.